# Google Play Store for private channel distribution

Tags: google-play, apk, google-apps

In my company, we want to distribute an android app for only internal users.

We have one Google apps account (admin account) with our own company's domain name (`xyz@sample.com`).

We have other employee's email id with the company domain name(`xyz@sample.com`) and these are not under the Google apps.

Do we need the same Google apps account for all the employees under Google apps admin? As we need to make the app downloadable to all the internal employees too.

OR

Is it possible to make the android app downloadable with our own server's created email ids.

For Google APP account, do we need to pay Rs.150/employee/month?

***EDIT:***

I do not want to publish my android app on other play store where Google can not interfere.Is there any store? I have searched and found that there are many stores available but which is trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is your app available on the web for a common download. After in android, you need to download the apk and notify the user to update.

Below is the code I use to download the .apk and install it.

```
public void UpdateApk(){

            String nameapk = "youapp.apk";
            String urlDownload = "http://youserver/" + nameapk;
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlDownload).openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            conn.setConnectTimeout(20000);

            conn.connect();

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, nameapk);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;

            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }

            fos.close();
            is.close();


            // till here, it works fine - .apk is download to 
            // sdcard in download file

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + nameapk)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            youcontext.startActivity(intent);

    }
```

To check the version of the app, see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14313280/185022

Comment: In my case, I decided to create a website to publish my app. There, the upload process, identifies the version of the app, creates its folder with the version number and the stores it. I created a webservice to return the number of the largest existing folder in the repository. So the app checks the latest version available and checks if it is greater than the current in the device, only after, downloading and installing.