# Java/Android Displaying .apk files as files but with their icons

Tags: android, listview, icons, apk, baseadapter

I am building a root app allowing to debloat apk files from system/app and system/priv app. I have a ListView that takes the content of both dirs and filters them against a string array that I built (not all apps can be debloated). It feeds into a list with multiple choice mode. 
Now, what I can't manage is how to display apk files with their icons.
I am using a simple adapter for now. But I can switch to base adapter. What I need is a way to add the app icons into the Image View. 
I am not using the package manager to generate the list, for several reasons I need it to be the actual apk files that are displayed.
Can someone please help me with a way to make an apk file display with it's icon? Like in root explorer f.e.?
This is the main part of code that takes care of the list for now:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
                implements View.OnClickListener,
                AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Button debloat;
    ListView appList;
    File app = new File("/system/app");
    File privApp = new File("/system/priv-app");
    ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList;
    BufferedWriter debloatBW;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    debloat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    debloat.setOnClickListener(this);

    appList = getListView();

    File[] files = app.listFiles();
    File[] files1 = privApp.listFiles();
    List<String> relevantApps = 
        Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.include_apk));
    fileList.clear();
    for (File file : files){
        if (file.isFile()
            && file.getPath().endsWith(".apk")
            && relevantApps.contains(file.getName().toString()))
        {
            fileList.add(file.getName());
        }

    }
    for (File file1 : files1) {
        if (file1.isFile()
            && file1.getPath().endsWith(".apk")
            && relevantApps.contains(file1.getName().toString()))
        {
            fileList.add(file1.getName());
        }
    }

    directoryList  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, fileList);

    appList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    appList.setAdapter(directoryList);




}
```

Thank you for any advice you might have!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend creating your own custome adapter in which you inflate the row as usuala and then set the text, to get the icon of the package with the help of this post [Get Apk Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661418/get-apk-file-icon-version-name) and set it to the ImageView in the row. How to create a custome adapter you find out bets with this tutorial [Using Android ListView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).

Comment: this seems to be it. I will build the custom adapter and let you know how it worked for me. Thank you!