# Application Info of a non installed app

Tags: java, android, file, android-package-managers, android-applicationinfo

i am trying to get some info (name and icon) from a non installed app. Basically o got the apk file, i didn't installed it yet, but i would like to display its name and icon in a list.

I am trying to do this :

```
public void getReceivedApps() {
    packageManager = getPackageManager();
    System.out.println("TRANSFER-RECORDActivityThe received filePath is : " + receivedFilePath);

    PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageArchiveInfo(receivedFilePath, PackageManager.GET_GIDS);
    System.out.println("TRANSFER RECORD ACTIVYT : O TO STRING TO PACKAGE INFO : " + packageInfo.toString());
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageInfo.applicationInfo;
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "packaginf0 : " + applicationInfo.toString());
    String appName = applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();

    System.out.println("TRANSFER RECORD ACTIVITY  : THE APPNAME IS : " + appName);
    Drawable icon = packageManager.getPackageArchiveInfo(receivedFilePath, PackageManager.GET_GIDS).applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager);
    //then add it to a list.
}
```

The problem and it is giving me a nullpointerexception in the loadIcon and loadLabel instructions.

Btw, the `receivedFilePath` string has the filepath to that apk file (which is

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/"+getIntent().getStringExtra("receivedFilePath"); )
```

And this receivedFilePath sent as a string has the name of the file (not the app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a similar problem, hope it helps:

```
String APKFilePath = "mnt/sdcard/myapkfile.apk"; //For example...

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
PackageInfo    pi = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(APKFilePath, 0);

// the secret are these two lines....
pi.applicationInfo.sourceDir       = APKFilePath;
pi.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir = APKFilePath;
//

Drawable APKicon = pi.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
String   AppName = (String)pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm);
```

REF: [Get apk file icon, version, name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661418/get-apk-file-icon-version-name/14313280#14313280)

Comment: Thank you, it worked ! Apparently the archiveInfo is just for installed apps